# Storing user._id in cookie for later use

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cookies, jwt

I am writing a application that uses JWTs for user authentication. I am trying to allow the user to submit or edit resources associated ONLY to there ID which is generated when they create their account in MongoDB only after the user has logged in. My instructor suggested to store the user._id within a cookie but not familiar with that process. Any tips on how I could accomplish this?

Here is an example of how my users are registered within the server

```
app.get('/register',  function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/register.html');
    });
app.post('/register',  async function (req,res) {

  try {
    req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    var newUser = new User(req.body);
    newUser.save(function(error,user){
      res.redirect('/login');
    });  
  } catch{
    res.redirect('/register');
  }
  // console.log(newUser);
});
```

Here is the auth process

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = process.env.secret;

module.exports = new JwtStrategy(opts, async (jwt_payload,done)=> {
    const user = await (req.body.email);
    if( jwt_payload.email === req.body.email){
        return done(null, true)
    }
    
    try {
        if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)){
            return done(null, user);
         } else {
             return done(null, false, { message: "Password is incorrect"});
         }
    } catch (e) {
        return done(e);
    }
    
})
```

Here is logging in

```
app.post('/login',  async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body
    const user = await User.findOne({ username }).lean()
    if (!user) {

        return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/401.html');
    }
    if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        // the username, password combination is successful
        const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                id: user._id,
                username: user.username
            },
            process.env.secret
    )

    console.log(user._id);
    //I need to find a way to send over the user._id to the client side so it can be stored later to allow the user to only update their resources and to view their resources
        return res.redirect('/welcome.html');
  }

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/401.html');
})
```

EDIT: I am not not wanting to store the token unless that is the only way to pass the user._id to the client side due to security reasoning.

Technologies I am using are, Node.js, Express.js, Mongoose, MongoDB, JWT, passport, jwt-simple, bcrypt, methodOverride, and secrets for resetting the users password and creating the user are stored in an .env.

Comment: Did you read about [npm cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie). It's middleware for express to write / read cookies. BE SURE to use a secure cookie for this application; it's too easy for cybercreeps to spoof user ids otherwise.

Comment: Yes, storing a JWT token in a cookie is not uncommon. However, for us to help you, we will need more context. The question is much too broad. The only way to answer it is to say use any cookie library for node and store the token. It's that simple.

Comment: I don't see your jwt token actually being generated anywhere in your code. Show the part that uses this variable `opts.secretOrKey`. Or this variable `process.env.secret`.